# How to read Location of a view whilst it is being animated

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am animating a small space ship (derived from UIView) and periodically (whilst in animation) send it a PointF to check if this is near the space ship's current position.
However, when reading out the Frame position of the View it keeps returning the starting position before the animation started.

I think this is by design but it is causing me big problems since the space ship(s) should move independently along Paths and it is very tricky for me to do this by hand.

Is there another way - and/or has anyone some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of a workaround for your issue, but I have some suggestions on game development for iOS.

Your problem is one of the reasons why using GUI frameworks like UIKit/CoreGraphics for games isn't a good idea.  For both performance reasons, as well as the fact as they aren't designed for it.

If you are looking for a simple framework for making games on iOS, have you looked at [MonoGame](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame)? If you are doing lots of animations, we also use [XNA Tweener](http://xnatweener.codeplex.com/) along with MonoGame to get some lifelike animations.

PS - check out our game [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7gtAWHSadI&feature=plcp).